# How do I figure out what parameters my tree method needs?

Tags: java, tree

This is the error im getting

```
  startTree.insert(data[0], Integer.parseInt(data[1]), startTree);
           ^
  symbol:   method insert(String,int,TwoThreeTree)
  location: variable startTree of type TwoThreeTree
```

even though I have this method in the TwoThreeTree class

`public static void insert(String key, int value, TwoThreeTree tree) {`

this is how i made the twothree tree

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read sc from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int intSc = sc.nextInt();
        TwoThreeTree startTree = new TwoThreeTree();     

        for (int i = 0; i < intSc + 1; i++) {
            String planetMap = sc.nextLine();
            if (planetMap.length() == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            String[] planets = planetMap.split(" ");
            startTree.insert((String)planets[0], (int)Integer.parseInt(planets[1]), (TwoThreeTree)startTree);
        }
```

Why am I getting this error? I am not sure why other than that the method might not be public? but i made it public and it still did not work.

Comment: You left out the important part. The error message.

Comment: @user207421 the error message is at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error when you try to call a method on object, that does not exist.

Example using `jshell`,

```
jshell> Integer x = 100;
x ==> 100

jshell> x.multiply(2)
|  Error:
|  cannot find symbol
|    symbol:   method multiply(int)
|  x.multiply(2)
|  ^--------^
```

So in your example `startTree` does not have a method `insert`.

*I don't know the type of `startTree`, but try casting to `TwoThreeTree` if it is of type `TwoThreeTree`*

Comment: But I have this code in my tree class class twothree {

   static void insert(String key, int value, TwoThreeTree tree) {

Comment: what is the type of `startTree`? what what is the accessibility of `insert`? is it public

Comment: the type of startTree is TwoThreeTree and insert is public

Comment: well based on your question, `static void insert` which makes it only accessible from package.

Comment: how could i fix this @prayagupd

Comment: try making it `public void insert`. Also can you please update your question to show how you created `startTree`?